# XSLT failing to color rows based on element values?

Tags: xml, xslt

I need to color rows depending upon data values.  If department is "CIT" the row has to be cyan; if it's "COMP", yellow; if it's "IS", pink; anything else, grey. I have everything as it needs to be, but I am getting only grey.  That is the only thing with which I'm having an issue.

XML Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <catalog>
    <semester name="Fall 2016">
       <class>
           <dept> CIT </dept>
           <number>270/L</number>
           <title>Integrative Programming</title>
           <prereq>CIT 160/L, COMP 182/L; MATH 103, 150A OR 255A</prereq>
       </class>

    <class>
    <dept> SOC  </dept>
    <number>340</number>
    <title>Sociology Of Work</title>
    <prereq>SOC 150</prereq>
   </class>
</semester>
<semester name="Spring 2017">
<class>
    <dept> CIT </dept>
    <number>360</number>
    <title>System Management</title>
    <prereq>CIT 210/L, 270/L</prereq>
</class>
</semester>
<semester name="Fall 2017">
    <class>
    <dept> CIT </dept>
    <number>480/L</number>
    <title> CIT System Design And Implementation1  </title>
    <prereq>COMP 484/L, IS 451</prereq>
</class>
<class>
    <dept> COMP </dept>
    <number>424</number>
    <title>Computer System Security</title>
    <prereq>CIT 360, IS 435</prereq>
</class>
<class>
    <dept> COMP </dept>
    <number>484/L</number>
    <title> Web Engineering I </title>
    <prereq>CIT 360</prereq>
</class>
<class>
    <dept> COMP </dept>
    <number>485</number>
    <title>Human Computer Interaction</title>
    <prereq>CIT 360, IS 451</prereq>
</class>
</semester>
<semester name="Spring 2018">
    <class>
    <dept> CIT </dept>
    <number>481/L</number>
    <title>CIT System Design And Implementation II</title>
    <prereq>CIT 480/L</prereq>
</class>
```

XSLT Code:

```
 <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
        <body>
            <h2>Path to Graduation</h2>
            <xsl:for-each select="catalog/semester">
                <h2><xsl:value-of select="@name"/></h2>
                <table border="1">
                    <tr bgcolor="lightgreen">
                        <th style="align:center;width:120px;">Catalog Number</th>
                        <th style="align:center;width:350px;">Title</th>
                        <th style="align:center;width:300px;">Prerequisites</th>
                    </tr>
                    <xsl:for-each select="class">
                        <xsl:choose>
                            <xsl:when test="dept='CIT'">
                                <tr bgcolor="cyan">
                                    <td align="center"><xsl:value-of select="dept"/>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="number"/></td>
                                    <td align="center"><xsl:value-of select="title"/></td>
                                    <td align="center"><xsl:value-of select="prereq"/></td>
                                </tr>
                            </xsl:when>
                            <xsl:when test="dept='IS'">
                                <tr bgcolor="pink">
                                    <td align="center"><xsl:value-of select="dept"/>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="number"/></td>
                                    <td align="center"><xsl:value-of select="title"/></td>
                                    <td align="center"><xsl:value-of select="prereq"/></td>
                                </tr>
                            </xsl:when>

                            <xsl:when test="dept='COMP'">
                                <tr bgcolor="yellow">
                                    <td align="center"><xsl:value-of select="dept"/>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="number"/></td>
                                    <td align="center"><xsl:value-of select="title"/></td>
                                    <td align="center"><xsl:value-of select="prereq"/></td>
                                </tr>

                            </xsl:when>
                            <xsl:otherwise>
                                <tr bgcolor="grey">
                                    <td align="center"><xsl:value-of select="dept"/>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="number"/></td>
                                    <td align="center"><xsl:value-of select="title"/></td>
                                    <td align="center"><xsl:value-of select="prereq"/></td>
                                </tr>
                            </xsl:otherwise>
                        </xsl:choose>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </table>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `xsl:when` tests against `dept` are failing because of leading and trailing spaces.

Test against `normalize-space(dept)` rather than `dept` to eliminate the problem.

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of things that you need to fix in your XML or make provision in your XSLT to trim the spaces,

There are spaces in your `node` hence your condition was failing,

Issue node :

```
<dept> CIT </dept>
```

Correct node :

```
<dept>CIT</dept>
```

I have fixed your XML you can find working : http://xsltransform.net/ejivdHb/28

Or alternatively you can use following approaches to fix your XSL,

1. Using normalize-space()

   ```
   <xsl:when test="normalize-space(dept)='CIT'">
   ```
2. Using regular expression.

   ```
   <!-- (XSL 2.0) -->
   <xsl:when test="replace(dept, '^\s+|\s+$', '')='CIT'">
   ```

Comment: Generally as developers we should make our code more robust rather than change input data to accommodate existing code.  Given that I've [already shown](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41008397/290085) OP how to make the XSLT more robust, it's rather strange (and quite counterproductive) for you to now suggest that OP change the input XML instead.

Comment: @kjhughes OP XML is inconsistent. Only some nodes has spaces which caused those failing conditions. So for me it is better to suggest OP to make input XML consistent. I hope you agree on this.

Comment: Fixing the code that produces inconsistent XML: noble.  Avoiding fixing code that consumes inconsistent XML by manually changing XML: not noble.

Comment: The OP is using XSLT 1.0, so `replace()` isn't going to work. You could use `translate()` instead, but `normalize-space()` is cleaner anyway in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a better way of writing your code that not only solves the whitespace problems, it also does it "the XSLT way" which is to use template rules.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
    <body>
      <h2>Path to Graduation</h2>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="catalog/semester"/>
    </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="semester">
  <h2><xsl:value-of select="@name"/></h2>
  <table border="1">
     <tr bgcolor="lightgreen">
       <th style="align:center;width:120px;">Catalog Number</th>
       <th style="align:center;width:350px;">Title</th>
       <th style="align:center;width:300px;">Prerequisites</th>
     </tr>
     <xsl:apply-templates select="class"/>
  </table>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="class[normalize-space(dept)='CIT']"
    mode="color">cyan</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="class[normalize-space(dept)='IS']"
    mode="color">pink</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="class[normalize-space(dept)='COMP']"
    mode="color">yellow</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="class" 
    mode="color">grey</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="class">
  <tr bgcolor="cyan">
    <xsl:attribute name="bgcolor">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="color"/>
    </xsl:attribute>
    <td><xsl:value-of select="number"/></td>
    <td align="center"><xsl:value-of select="title"/></td>
    <td align="center"><xsl:value-of select="prereq"/></td>
 </tr>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Next week's lesson: the HTML5 table model and CSS.